# Building dynamic WHERE clause in stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I'm using SQL Server 2008 Express, and I have a stored procedure that do a `SELECT` from table, based on parameters. I have `nvarchar` parameters and `int` parameters.

Here is my problem, my where clause looks like this:

```
WHERE [companies_SimpleList].[Description] Like @What 
    AND companies_SimpleList.Keywords Like @Keywords
    AND companies_SimpleList.FullAdress Like @Where
    AND companies_SimpleList.ActivityId = @ActivityId
    AND companies_SimpleList.DepartementId = @DepartementId
    AND companies_SimpleList.CityId = @CityId
```

This parameters are the filter values set by the user of my ASP.NET MVC 3 application, and the `int` parameters may not be set, so their value will be 0. This is my problem, the stored procedure will search for items who have `0` as `CityId` for example, and for this, it return a wrong result. So it will be nice, to be able to have a dynamic where clause, based on if the value of int parameter is grater than 0, or not.

Thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [Optional where clause / parameter in a SQL 2008 stored proc?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1723375/optional-where-clause-parameter-in-a-sql-2008-stored-proc)

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
WHERE 1 = 1
AND (@what     IS NULL OR [companies_SimpleList].[Description] Like @What )
AND (@keywords IS NULL OR companies_SimpleList.Keywords        Like @Keywords)
AND (@where    IS NULL OR companies_SimpleList.FullAdress      Like @Where)
...
```

If any of the parameters `@what`, `@where` is sent to the stored procedure with `NULL` value then the condition will be ignored. You can use 0 instead of null as a test value then it will be something like `@what = 0 OR ...`

Comment: +1 This is the mechanism I teach to junior developers. It's well-optimised by SQL Server and is one of the easier forms of this logic to read.

Comment: Co-workers discourage me to use this approach because "the query will evaluate the same conditions for every row (e.g.: @what is null) and it will affect performance". Are they right? Tragedian, where I can find some proof of the "well-optimisation" you wrote about?

Comment: Yes, it is not the best performance wise solution. But the answer was the solution for the OP problem. You can handle this from the application side instead of doing this this way.

Comment: In case you were wondering (like me) if the WHERE 1=1 was in some form part of the solution, I don't believe it is. Its just for syntactical convenience to make all the where statements line up.

Comment: This is great!! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

try something like

```
AND companies_SimpleList.CityId = @CityId or @CityID = 0
```

Comment: Parentheses around the two `OR`ed terms would be a good idea.

Comment: Agreed, bit slack of me that. I don't like depending on order of precedence either.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear, I meant that in the context of the OP's query `AND companies_SimpleList.CityId = @CityId or @CityID = 0` is quite different from `AND ( companies_SimpleList.CityId = @CityId or @CityID = 0 )`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another easy-to-read solution for SQL Server >=2008

```
CREATE PROCEDURE FindEmployee
    @Id INT = NULL,
    @SecondName NVARCHAR(MAX) = NULL
AS 
    SELECT  Employees.Id AS "Id",
            Employees.FirstName AS "FirstName",
            Employees.SecondName AS "SecondName"
    FROM Employees
    WHERE Employees.Id = COALESCE(@Id, Employees.Id)
    AND Employees.SecondName LIKE COALESCE(@SecondName, Employees.SecondName) + '%'
```

Comment: This should be avoided in favor of the accepted answer. see [The Coalesce Trap](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#coalesce)