# Conditional where logic

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I have a SQL Server stored procedure where I want to add a conditional clause based on a parameter (`@action`). So if a action is `X` or `Y` then I don't want to use the where clause (and want to fetch all records), but if the action is NOT `X` OR `Y` then I want to fetch only those records that match with other parameter (`@username`).

I am trying this:

```
AND CASE 
        WHEN (ISNULL(@action, '') = 'X' OR ISNULL(@action, '') = 'Y')
            THEN a.name 
            ELSE a.name 
    END = @username
```

This seems to work ok if the action is not X or Y, however it does not return any data if the action is X.

How can I return all records (basically ignore the `Where` clause) if the action is X or Y?

Comment: `Then a.name else a.name`? This means that the `CASE` will always resolve to `a.name` so you might as well have `a.name`. Though using a `CASE` in the `WHERE` is rarely the correct solution; instead use explicit `AND` and `OR` logic.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Building dynamic WHERE clause in stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11396919/building-dynamic-where-clause-in-stored-procedure)

Comment: @ThomA I am modifying existing procedure where they are using cases. What would be the best way to add a conditional where clause? could you give an example?

Comment: `WHERE (@var = 'X' AND Col = 'A') OR (@Var = 'B' AND Col = 'Q')`. Additionally see [Catch-all queries](https://www.sqlinthewild.co.za/index.php/2009/03/19/catch-all-queries/) and [Kitchen Sink Queries](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example)

Comment: The easiest solution in this example is to entirely remove the case expression. But if you are looking for something like the case expression could be a couple of values something like `case when @action in ('x', 'y')` would work.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm trying `case when @action not in ('x', 'y') then a.name = @username` and it gives syntax error at `=`. It also expects 'else condition' in which i dont want to select any value for a.name, how can I do that?

Comment: `and a.name = case when @action not in('x', 'y') then @username else a.name end`

Comment: What's wrong with simple boolean logic `and (@action in ('x', 'y') or a.name = @username)`

Comment: The syntax error is because in the code you posted in your comment is missing the `end`. To not have another value simply omit the `else` or have ir return a.name.

Answer (score 3):

Just use plain conditions - essentially expressing your English description using SQL:

```
WHERE (@action NOT IN ('X', 'Y') OR a.name = @username)
-- plus any other conditions
```

Comment: Or just `WHERE (@action NOT IN ('X', 'Y') OR a.name = @username)` ?

Comment: @Charlieface much better...

Comment: Just be aware of what a kitchen sink query is, as already posted earlier by @Thom A https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/backtobasics-updated-kitchen-sink-example

Answer (score -1):

maybe this -

```
AND (CASE 
        WHEN (ISNULL(@action, '') = 'X' OR ISNULL(@action, '') = 'Y')  THEN 1
        WHEN ISNULL(@action, '') <> 'X' AND  ISNULL(@action, '') <> 'Y' AND a.name = @username THEN 1
            ELSE 0 
    END) = 1
```

Comment: Don't use `CASE` in `WHERE`, just don't